# Defer loading of JavaScript (3 files)

Tags: javascript

All day I read and review on Defer loading in JavaScript and nothing. I tried with defer/async attributes and deferredfunctions.js(?).  What should I do with it and where to put it? Sorry for my ignorance.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mysite.com/files/js/mosaic.1.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){     $('.fade').mosaic();});</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is a little bit too widespreaded to answer correctly. Loading javascript code *asyncronously* / *deferred* and using a script-loaded should have a lot of different reasons.

Why should you load it deferred? Just for the same reason you should put all your `<script>` tags at the very bottom of your HTML markup. `<script>` elements do block the executing of the browsers HTML renderer. When a `<script>` elements gets encountered, the HTML parser will stop and load+evaluate that script file before it continues. This can have a more or less huge performance impact on page-loading times (depending on the number and size of your javascript files).

Thats the reason why you should tag your `<script>` elements with `async` and/or `deferr` attributes. If a browser understands those attributes (which pretty much every modern browser does) it will not stop, but load and evaluate the resource asyncronously.

You might say now, "*what about order and dependencies*", which would be a valid and good argument. If you flag all your scripts for the browser that allow to load them asyncronously, order is no longer guaranteed, which is a big problem if scripts depend on the presence of other scripts. Here is the point where third-party script loaders like *requireJS* come to the stage.

Comment: Interesting response. I think it's useful to mention require.js as well. Good answer.